# Как изменить URL Wordpress?

Tags: wordpress

есть такая ситуация
создал Custom Post Type с категориями

Страница Категории выглядит так: **site.ru/catg**
Но при заходе на страницу статьи идет **site.ru/customPostName/postName**
Можно ли сделать что бы URL был таким
**site.ru/catgName/PostName** без CustomPostName

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Когда регистрируете пост тип нужно указать атрибут rewrite. Подробнее тут:
https://wp-kama.ru/function/register_post_type#rewrite-massiv-logicheskij